# How to get data from onitemclick and display it on another activity (Android Dev)?

Tags: java, android

I am very new to Android and Java dev, sorry in advance.

I am making a simple music player app.

Right now my app gets storage data from the phone (it finds mp3 files) and displays both the title and artist in a ListView.

When a song item in the list is clicked it changes screens to the PlaySongActivity.Java via an intent. On the Activity_Play_Song.xml I set up two text views. I want to make it so that whenever an item is clicked the title and artist is transferred into the two text views in the Activity_Play_Song.xml texts.

How can I do this?

Here is my code:

**MainActivity**

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

 public void getMusic(){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor songCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null, null, null, null);

    if(songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst()){
        int songTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int songArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

        do{
            String currentTitle = songCursor.getString((songTitle));
            String currentArtist = songCursor.getString((songArtist));
            arrayList.add(currentTitle+ "\n" + currentArtist);
        } while (songCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}

public void doStuff(){
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    getMusic();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlaySongActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });


}
```

Currently, the PlaySongsActivity only contains the default onCreate code and the activity_play_songs.xml has two TextViews where I want the title and artist to go.

Comment: If my answer fixed your problem, please click the checkmark to show others that it did work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anjali bhardwaj.

To send information from one activity to another using intent do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlaySongActivity.class);

//Here we store the title and author strings using .putExtra("Name", Value)

i.putExtra("ArtistString", currentArtist);
i.putExtra("TitleString", currentTitle);

startActivity(i);
```

Now it is stored and will be sent over to the activity that you are starting.

To get the information in the receiving activity

```
/*gets the information from the intent that was passed and casts it to a Intent object*/
Intent intent = getIntent();

//gets the strings from the intent
String artist = intent.getStringExtra("ArtistString");
String title = intent.getStringExtra("TitleString");
```

Now you can do whatever you want with this string. Hope this helps!

--UPDATE--

Example

```
public class SomeClass{

//declare them outside of the method so that they can be accessed by any method. 
//I just set them to nothing so that you dont get NULLPOINTEREXCEPTIONs
String currentTitle = "nothing";
String currentArtist = "nothing";

public void getMusic(){
   //set the value of the strings in here
}

public void doStuff(){
  //Access them here
}

}
```

Comment: I am just getting an error with the currentArtist and currentTitle. It says to make it a local variable and to initialize it. Not sure what I should do. thank you so much btw.

Comment: @Anjalibhardwaj No problem! Now to your question: what it's saying is that you can't access the string variables because it was created inside the getMusic() method. In order to access the variable it must created inside of the class and outside of the getMusic() method. I have updated my answer with an example so that you can see what i mean.